# I can't figure out why my terraform environment main.tf can't recognize var declarations in a module variables.tf

Tags: terraform

My terraform project is structured like this:

```
├── environments
│   └── dev-1
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── terraform.tfvars
│       └── variables.tf
├── main.tf
├── modules
│   ├── ec2_instance
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── rds_instance
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   └── security_group
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── outputs.tf
│       └── variables.tf
├── outputs.tf
└── variables.tf
```

In `dev-1/main.tf`, I define variables in a module call:

```
module "some_ec2_security_group" {
  source          = "../../modules/security_group"
  environment     = var.environment
  vpc_id          = var.vpc_id
  ssh_ec2_cidr_blocks = var.ssh_ec2_cidr_blocks
}
```

hardcoded in `./terraform.tfvars`. If I declare the variables in `./variables.tf`, validation is successful, but if I declare them in the module variables.tf, in `../../modules/security_group/variable.tf`, validation fails with:

```
│ Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│ 
│   on main.tf line 22, in module "some_ec2_security_group":
│   22:   vpc_id          = var.vpc_id
│ 
│ An input variable with the name "vpc_id" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "vpc_id" {} block.
```

for each var that is not present in the environment `variables.tf` but is present in the module `variables.tf`. Am I understanding this incorrectly? I thought the purpose of declaring variables in modules is encouraged to minimize repetitive declaration, as all of these variables are needed for each environment.

I have tried reinitializing terraform multiple times, cleared cache. I am using

```
Terraform v1.7.2
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v5.34.0
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It happening because you trying to provide values to variables from `security_group` sub module with variables from `dev-1` module.

```
module "some_ec2_security_group" {
  source          = "../../modules/security_group"
  environment     = var.environment                 <- provides environment value
  vpc_id          = var.vpc_id                      <- provides vpc_id value
  ssh_ec2_cidr_blocks = var.ssh_ec2_cidr_blocks     <- provides ssh_ec2_cidr_blocks value
}
```

Terraform requires to have those varaibles to be defined in `dev-1` module! That why `dev-1/variables.tf` is required if you want to pass parameters via variables.

Checkout modules overview: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/modules/module